# Dynamically adding attributes without changing the java object

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to add another new attributes the an field without changing the java 
object.

```
<field  attribute1 = "1"  attribute2 = "2"  attribute3 = "3"> value</filed>

@XmlRootElement(name = "field ")
public class Field 
{
    @XmlAttribute(name="attribute1")
    private String attribute1;

    @XmlAttribute(name="attribute2")
    private String attribute2;

    @XmlAttribute(name="attribute3")
    private String attribute3;
}
```

If I want to add a new attribute 4  to the XMLwithout changing the Field class(adding new field to the class and recompile).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your want the Java class to be able to store any attribute, you need a `Map` to store the attribute name/value pairs, and you need to annotate that field with [`@XmlAnyAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyAttribute.html).

Here is example code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "field")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Field {
    @XmlAttribute(name="attribute1")
    String attribute1;

    @XmlAttribute(name="attribute2")
    String attribute2;

    @XmlAttribute(name="attribute3")
    String attribute3;

    @XmlAnyAttribute
    Map<String, String> attributes;
}
```

*Test*

```
String xml = "<field attribute1=\"A\"" +
                   " attribute2=\"B\"" +
                   " attribute3=\"C\"" +
                   " attribute4=\"D\"" +
                   " foo=\"Bar\" />";
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Field.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Field field = (Field) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
System.out.println("field.attribute1 = " + field.attribute1);
System.out.println("field.attribute2 = " + field.attribute2);
System.out.println("field.attribute3 = " + field.attribute3);
System.out.println("field.attributes = " + field.attributes);
```

*Output*

```
field.attribute1 = A
field.attribute2 = B
field.attribute3 = C
field.attributes = {attribute4=D, foo=Bar}
```

As you can see, the two "extra" attributes were added to the map.

If you run the same test but without any attributes, i.e. with `xml = "<field/>";`, you get:

```
field.attribute1 = null
field.attribute2 = null
field.attribute3 = null
field.attributes = null
```

The `attributes` field is left unassigned, i.e. `null`. It is not an empty map.